# SQL Design - Accounting for unknown values

Tags: sql, database-design

Say I have a table called HoursCharged

```
ChrgNum(varchar(10))   
CategoryID(uniqueidentifier)   
Month(datetime)   
Hours(int)
```

CategoryID is a foreign key reference to another table in my database, which is just a name/ID pairing.  ChrgNum is guaranteed to be unique outside of this database, and so I only check to see if it exists in my db already.

You should also know that this tool support several different groups from one database (hence the globally unique CategoryID, since different groups may potentially name the Categories the same thing, I needed to differentiate them).

This table is populated from a CSV file.  The idea is that every combination of ChrgNum, CategoryID, and Month is going to be unique.  The report that is being run to create the import file can only see a certain range (i.e. a year).  Therefore the algorithm looks something like this:

```
IF (ChrgNum exists in database, CategoryID exists in database, 
    combo of ChrgNum/CategoryID/Month DOES NOT exist in table HoursBurned)
THEN add a new row for this entry
ELSE IF (ChrgNum exists in database, CategoryID exists in database,
    combo of ChrgNum/CategoryID/Month DOES exist in table HoursBurned)
THEN update the existing row with the new Hours value.
```

This is all fine and good, except now my boss wants me to account for hours charged, in a particular month, for a known ChrgNum and an *unknown* Category.

My question is, how do I account for this?  If I simply insert a NULL CategoryID, what happens if a totally seperate group charges hours to the same number and category?  My other idea was to create a new table for the unknown Categories, but if I do this, and the first import has two unknown categories while the next one has one of the two again (which can happen) what do I do?

My head has been swirling around this for hours.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: seriously: do you need to keep apart the different "unknown" category ID's ? I like your idea of inserting into an "unknown categories" table. To handle the "unknown already exists", you could either to a programmatic check and only insert if it's not already in there, or add a unique constraint on the CategoryID and tell it to ignore duplicates.

Comment: No, the problem is that the report has a variable time span. Say I find two unknown categories in the first report run. The next time, I find one, and that one an exact duplicate of one of the earlier two. What happens to the row?

Comment: could you add an additional column to your "UnknownCategories" that would make this case unique? Something like a INT IDENTITY, or such? Not relying on the CategoryID to be unique?

Comment: Does your import file contain category names, or IDs?

Comment: Names. The Ids are internally generated by my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boss presented you with this problem, so why not ask them?  Because this really sounds like a business problem.  If you have groups which are reporting on categories you don't know about then surely you should be attempting to synchronize your database with the systems which feed it?

Otherwise, what is wrong with having a single "Unknown" category?  You are being asked to track the hours assigned to categories you don't currently track.

Comment: Believe it or not, this is the closest answer to what I actually did.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.  Usually in fact, although that doesn't mean we always get to implement things that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you should be adding the unrecognized categories to the existing categories table on the fly.  If the problem is then distinguishing between categories with the same name from different groups, don't you already have that problem now?

Comment: I don't want to add categories since they are selectable by users for other purposes.

Comment: If you're never going to add categories to the main table, you'd use the "unknown categories" table you talked about, probably with a column indicating which group provided it.  Then on each import, wouldn't you just see if the category exists in either table, and if not, add it to the unknown table?