# Combine two tables for one output

Tags: sql, union

Say I have two tables:

KnownHours:

```
ChargeNum    CategoryID    Month    Hours
111111       1             2/1/09   10
111111       1             3/1/09   30
111111       1             4/1/09   50
222222       1             3/1/09   40
111111       2             4/1/09   50
```

UnknownHours:

```
ChargeNum   Month   Hours
111111      2/1/09  70
111111      3/1/09  40.5
222222      7/1/09  25.5
```

I need to group these hours, ignoring Month, into a single data table so that my expected result is the following:

```
ChargeNum    CategoryID     Hours
111111       1              90
111111       2              50
111111       Unknown        110.5
222222       1              40
222222       Unknown        25.5
```

I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I need to sum the hours for each ChargeNum/Category combination.  I updated the sample data to reflect this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You'll need to use `UNION` to combine the results of two queries. In your case:

```
SELECT ChargeNum, CategoryID, SUM(Hours)
FROM KnownHours
GROUP BY ChargeNum, CategoryID
UNION ALL
SELECT ChargeNum, 'Unknown' AS CategoryID, SUM(Hours)
FROM UnknownHours
GROUP BY ChargeNum
```

Note - If you use `UNION ALL` as in above, it's no slower than running the two queries separately as it does no duplicate-checking.

Comment: I've heard this is exceptionally slow.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The only thing that would be possibly faster is to store the data in one table, not two. Use `CategoryID = NULL` for unknown hours.

Comment: @Matthew: Where did you hear that? `union all` is absolutely fast.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already had that conversation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209372/sql-design-accounting-for-unknown-values

Comment: His original answer was UNION, not UNION ALL.  That is what I was referring to.

Comment: UNIONs and UNION ALLs are OFTEN (if not always) faster than a commensurate "OR" in your filter.

Answer (score 15):

In your expected output, you've got the second last row sum incorrect, it should be 40 according to the data in your tables, but here is the query:

```
Select  ChargeNum, CategoryId, Sum(Hours)
From    (
    Select  ChargeNum, CategoryId, Hours
    From    KnownHours
    Union
    Select  ChargeNum, 'Unknown' As CategoryId, Hours
    From    UnknownHours
) As a
Group By ChargeNum, CategoryId
Order By ChargeNum, CategoryId
```

And here is the output:

```
ChargeNum  CategoryId 
---------- ---------- ----------------------
111111     1          40
111111     2          50
111111     Unknown    70
222222     1          40
222222     Unknown    25.5
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is what I needed to solve my problem! :)