# select two tables with different condtion

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

The `table1` has only index column and the table2 is just to contain versions.

I want to select every index and its latest version. (the yellow cells)

The `table2` has datetime column to know which one is latest.

When `table1.idx = table2.belongTo`, how to combine tables with a single query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Combine two tables for one output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227835/sql-combine-two-tables-for-one-output)

Comment: Could you try to add your exact db structure? An sqlfiddle would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit; Corrected the answer to return all columns from table2.

You first have to derive the second table by selecting max(datetime) and then join based on the condition you gave.

Here the second table `t2` will create row_number based on `max(datetime)` value for each `BelongTo`. Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652359/5234334) for it.

```
select t1.*,t2.idx,t2.belongTo,t2.datetime1
from table1 t1 
inner join 
(
    select t11.idx,t11.belongTo,t11.datetime1,count(*) as row_number from 
    table2 t11
    inner join table2 t12
    on t11.belongTo=t12.belongTo
    and t11.datetime1 <= t12.datetime1
    group by t11.belongTo,t11.datetime1
) t2 /*this table will create row_number based on max datetime value for each belongTo*/
on t1.idx=t2.belongTo
where t2.row_number=1
```

**See SQL Fiddle demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5ada/10